# Check if two items were returned from function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say I have the function:

```
def foo(i):
    if i == False:
        return 1, 2
    else:
        return 1
```

I want to check if two items were returned from the function, or just one - how do I do this?

Comment: `print foo(False)`? It is unclear what you want

Comment: 1) don't use `if i == False`; use `if not i:` instead. 2) `return` is not a function, don't try to call it. 3) `return (1)` returns just the `1` value, not a tuple. 4) in general you don't create functions that return different object types; better to return a tuple of two elements, always.

Comment: _(putting on my pedantic hat)_ You're returning one item in either case. If i is true, you return one integer. if i is false, you return one tuple ;-)

Comment: `f = foo(True); 2 if isinstance(f,tuple) else 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the length of the returned value, and catch a `TypeError` in case you have an int.

```
ret = foo(i)
try:
  if len(ret) == 2:
    print "It's a tuple!"
  else:
    print "Maybe it's a list?"
except TypeError:
  print "It's probably an int!"
```

**Note** that if you returned a list, then `len()` would work correctly instead of throwing a `TypeError`, and you have more conditions to check for. But if you know that it will be either a tuple or a single integer, this should work.

It's easier to ask forgiveness than permission, as they say.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that if `i` is `True`, then you return an **integer**. Otherwise you return a **tuple**. So you can write a test like this:

```
def footest(i):
        if isinstance(foo(i),int):
                print "one item was returned!"
        else:
                print "two items were returned!"
```

Here, `isinstance` is a **type-check**, a preferred version of `type(foo(i))==int`.

Answer (score -1):

Your current code returns an `int` if `i` is `True`, otherwise it returns a `tuple`. You can check for type with `isinstance`

```
>>> isinstance(foo(False), int) # foo(False) is a tuple, so this should be False
False
>>> isinstance(foo(True), int) # foo(True) is an int, so this should be True
True
```

Comment: The function does **not** return a tuple when `True` is passed in. You'll get an error instead; `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`.

Comment: this is not correct, why use an example that does not work and show output as if it does?

Comment: Just noticed that... Should be fixed now

Answer (score -1):

i think depending on how you receive your return, you might have an error. If you're receiving it correctly, the easy way in this very specific case of one or two would be to check if the second element exists i.e. if answer(2): or check then length of your tuple, answer.length.

Comment: sorry, been working on java; the above is correct, len(answer)

Comment: You can [edit] your answer to correct that, no need to comment.

Comment: But note that `foo(True)` returns an integer, an object with no length.